# How to install VS help using WIX x86 installer on a x64 platform?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, platform

I've been struggling with installing a CAB Help file (generated from a MSHC) using WIX. The basic recipe I tried to follow is the one here: [Installing Help with Help Library Manager and WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627758/installing-help-with-help-library-manager-and-wix) .

In my particular case I'm not really struggling with the recipe but with x64/x86 targets. I've read the WIX hints from [WiX tricks and tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-tips/577793) that describe how to make 2 installers, one for each target. However, since I prefer to have just one installer rather than 2, I chose to implement only a x86 target.

When I install using a x64 platform everything works fine. When I try to do the same thing for x86, it complains that it cannot find `HelpLibManager.exe`. On closer inspection, this seems reasonable, because this is installed in the 64-bit `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\HelpLibManager.exe`, while WIX uses the x86 folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\HelpLibManager.exe`.

To fix this, I attempted to read the correct path from the registry that contains where HelpLibManager is installed:

```
<Property Id="HELPLIB">
  <RegistrySearch Id="HelpLib"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="Software\Microsoft\Help\v1.0"
                  Name="AppRoot"
                  Type="raw" />
</Property>

<SetProperty Id="HELPLIBMANAGER"
         Value="[HELPLIB]HelpLibManager.exe"
         After="InstallInitialize"
         Sequence="execute"/>
```

When you look into the registry, (within the `Wow6432Node` of course), it tells me that the value of this key is: `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\` - which is correct. However, when I look at the log of the MSI, it reads `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\HelpLibManager.exe"`, which is incorrect:

```
Property(S): HELPLIB = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\
```

So apparently Wix changes the string value I read from the registry.

Can anyone explain to me what the proper way is to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirection to (x86) folder is done by Windows Installer automatically, not by WiX. The same happens if you are creating the package with [other setup authoring tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer#Tools) too.

Unfortunately a 32-bit installer cannot write in "Program Files" folder on x64 machines. WOW redirection from the OS controls this during the install.

For creating a registry entry directly under HKLM\Software and not under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node you can simply mark its component as 64-bit. Unfortunately this does not work the same for files, i.e. even if the component of the file is marked as a 64-bit one the OS will still redirect all files and folders under Program Files (x86).

**EDIT:**

> What I'm most surprised of is that the string value read from the registry is being changed (see the dumped property value)

I know, that surprised I was too when this happened the first time for me.

To launch a file from that folder you could still have a chance, using a little trick, if you write a [small custom action C#, with a DLL as output](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-c-sharp-ca.html). You could get the value of the search in the custom action, parse it, and if present, manually remove the "(x86)" portion. Then [temporarily disable WOW redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), launch your file, after which you re-enable WOW redirection.

Don't forget to set a condition on the custom action, to run only VersionNT64 property is set, and only on install.

Comment: Thanks... However, I'm not looking to write a file, I'm attempting to start an executable. What I'm most surprised of is that the string value read from the registry is being changed (see the dumped property value) - I'm not even attempting to access anything at that moment... The registry key is available for both x86 and x64 and have the same value.

Comment: Ough that's ugly... So that means I guess I have to choose between 2 installers (which sucks) or a very ugly hack based on your excellent info on how to solve this (which also sucks)... I think I'm seriously going to consider the former poison and disabling the installer for the other platform in WIX... I thought my first assumption that it does a 'replace' was wrong and that I made a bug, but you confirmed that it is really *that* ugly... damn. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like complete Bogdan Mitrache's answer with an exemple.
To perform this i use a C# custom action to acces registry and control the WOW behavior.

```
public partial class CustomActions
    {

        #region marshalling RegCreateKeyEx RegOpenKeyEx RegCloseKey RegSetValueEx
        [Flags]
        public enum RegOption
        {
            NonVolatile = 0x0,
            Volatile = 0x1,
            CreateLink = 0x2,
            BackupRestore = 0x4,
            OpenLink = 0x8
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum RegSAM
        {
            QueryValue = 0x0001,
            SetValue = 0x0002,
            CreateSubKey = 0x0004,
            EnumerateSubKeys = 0x0008,
            Notify = 0x0010,
            CreateLink = 0x0020,
            WOW64_32Key = 0x0200,
            WOW64_64Key = 0x0100,
            WOW64_Res = 0x0300,
            Read = 0x00020019,
            Write = 0x00020006,
            Execute = 0x00020019,
            AllAccess = 0x000f003f
        }

        public enum RegResult
        {
            CreatedNewKey = 0x00000001,
            OpenedExistingKey = 0x00000002
        }

        //[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        //public class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        //{
        //    public int nLength;
        //    public unsafe byte* lpSecurityDescriptor;
        //    public int bInheritHandle;
        //}
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int nLength;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public int bInheritHandle;
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int RegCreateKeyEx(
                    RegistryHive hKey,
                    string lpSubKey,
                    int Reserved,
                    string lpClass,
                    RegOption dwOptions,
                    RegSAM samDesired,
                    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
                    out UIntPtr phkResult,
                    out RegResult lpdwDisposition);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "RegOpenKeyEx")]
        static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(
            RegistryHive hKey,
            string subKey,
            uint options,
            RegSAM sam,
            out UIntPtr phkResult);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int RegCloseKey(
            UIntPtr hKey);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint RegSetValueEx(
             UIntPtr hKey,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
     string lpValueName,
             int Reserved,
             RegistryValueKind dwType,
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpData,
             int cbData);

        const int KEY_WOW64_64KEY = 0x0100;
        const int KEY_READ = 0x20019;

        #endregion

   private static uint WriteValue_String(UIntPtr hKey, string sName, string sValue)
        {
            uint setRes = RegSetValueEx(hKey, sName, 0, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String, sValue, sValue.Length + 1);
            return setRes;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enable AutoLogon by changing the values of the system registry keys "DefaultUserName", "DefaultPassword" and "AutoAdminLogon" 
        /// in "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="session"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult EnableAutoLogon(Session session)
        {
            _session = session;
            LogUtil.WriteDebugInfo(session, "Enter Function");
            try
            {

                SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttribs = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();

                UIntPtr hKey;
                RegResult regResult;

                LogUtil.WriteDebugInfo(session, "RegOpenKeyEx");
                int result = RegOpenKeyEx(
                    RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                    @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon",
                    0, //must be 0
                    RegSAM.WOW64_64Key | RegSAM.SetValue,
                    out hKey);

                LogUtil.WriteDebugInfo(session, "WriteValue_String");
                uint setRes = WriteValue_String(hKey, "DefaultUserName", "admin");
                setRes = WriteValue_String(hKey, "DefaultPassword", "admin");
                setRes = WriteValue_String(hKey, "AutoAdminLogon", "1");

                LogUtil.WriteDebugInfo(session, "RegCloseKey");
                int closeRes = RegCloseKey(hKey);           
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                LogUtil.WriteDebugInfo(session, "Exception occured : " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                LogUtil.WriteDebugInfo(session, "Exit Function");
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }
            LogUtil.WriteDebugInfo(session, "Exit Function");
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
 }
```

> KEY_WOW64_32KEY (0x0200)   Indicates that an application on 64-bit
> Windows should operate on the 32-bit registry view. This flag is
> ignored by 32-bit Windows. For more information, see Accessing an
> Alternate Registry View.
>
> This flag must be combined using the OR operator with the other flags
> in this table that either query or access registry values.
>
> Windows 2000:  This flag is not supported.
>
> KEY_WOW64_64KEY (0x0100)   Indicates that an application on 64-bit
> Windows should operate on the 64-bit registry view. This flag is
> ignored by 32-bit Windows. For more information, see Accessing an
> Alternate Registry View.
>
> This flag must be combined using the OR operator with the other flags
> in this table that either query or access registry values.
>
> Windows 2000:  This flag is not supported.