# Installshield LE won't install a 32-bit executable into Program Files on 64-bit Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield

I'm making installers for plug-ins using the InstallShield LE built in to Visual Studio 2010.  The plug-ins run in separate processes, so they are always 32-bit even if the host application is 64-bit.  The plugins must be installed to the same directory as the host application.  Therefore, the plugins should always install in `Program Files` even on 64-bit Windows - not `Program Files (x86)`.

InstallShield's `[ProgramFilesFolder]` predefined folder detects that the project output is 32-bit and evaluates to `Program Files (x86)` on a 64-bit machine.

I thought I could get around this by using a fixed folder instead of `[ProgramFilesFolder]`.  But Installshield appears to change it to `Program Files (x86)` anyway!  I guess it's trying to be helpful.

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection is done by the OS, not by InstallShield. The same applies for MSI packages built with other setup authoring tools. I explained this with more details in
[How to install VS help using WIX x86 installer on a x64 platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977712/how-to-install-vs-help-using-wix-x86-installer-on-a-x64-platform/14999502#14999502)

Comment: Wow, that is unbelievably annoying.